# Java -- Error cannot find symbol

Tags: java, swing

I don't understand why I get the "Error cannot find symbol" in several spots. Can somebody please shed some light on this simple problem.

- PriceCalculator.java:18: error: cannot find symbol  --- private JTextFeild priceFeild1;
- PriceCalculator.java:19: error: cannot find symbol --- private JTextFeild priceFeild2;
- PriceCalculator.java:41: error: cannot find symbol --- setDefaultCloseOpperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
- PriceCalculator.java:44: error: cannot find symbol --- buildPanel();

  ```
  import javax.swing.*;
  public class PriceCalculator extends JFrame
  {
  private JPanel panel;                               // References the panel

  private JLabel messageLabel1;                       // References the whole sale label
  private JLabel messageLabel2;                       // References the markup label percentage

  private JTextFeild priceFeild1;                 // References the whole sale price
  private JTextFeild priceFeild2;                 // Referencts the markup label percentage

  private JButton calcButton;                     // References the calculator button

  private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 550;           // References the window width
  private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 550;          // Referenecs the window height

  /** 

  Constructor below

  */

  public PriceCalculator()
  {
  // Set the window title
  setTitle("Retail Price Calculator");

  // Set the size of the window
  setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

  // Set the [x] exit button to close the program for the user
  setDefaultCloseOpperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  // Build the panel and add it to the JFrame
  buildPanel();

  // Add the contents to the panels frame
  add(panel);

  // Display the window here
  setVisible(true);
  }




  /**

  Main Method Below

  */

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
  new PriceCalculator();
  }

  }
  ```

Comment: Raptor's answer is completely right; I just would recommend you to use IDE to prevent you from typos in classes/methods.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean

Answer (score 4):

It is because you spell it wrong (`JTextFeild`). It should be `JTextField`.

Also, `setDefaultCloseOperation` instead of `setDefaultCloseOpperation`

Comment: Also, get an IDE like Eclipse. Such a trivial mistake would be easily spotted by an intelligent code editor, which would also offer suggestions how to fix it (like offering similar, but correctly spelled known types and methods). You appear to be making it harder than necessary for yourself :)

Answer (score 0):

Your spelling mistake :

`JTextFeild` instead of `JTextField`

and `setDefaultCloseOpperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` 
instead of `setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` you have used 2 `p` in `Operation`.